# Google (Play) Location Services Update Interval Changes in Sleep Mode (Android)

Tags: android, service, location, sleep, intervals

I have an app that periodically uploads a user's location to a server.

This is done with a class, LocationService, which is a *bound* IntentService.  The reason being that it needs to continue to dependably report location even when minimized.

In the MainActivity, the user clicks on a toggle button to indicate that they want to begin reporting their location (or toggle off to stop it).  This button is what triggers the location service to be started and bound (or stopped/killed).  The Location Service uses Google Play Location Services... here is some code from it:

```
public class MyLocationService
    extends IntentService
    implements GoogleApiClient.ConnectionCallbacks, GoogleApiClient.OnConnectionFailedListener, LocationListener
{

private final IBinder myBinder = new MyLocalBinder();

protected static final String TAG = "DXX MyLocationService";
protected GoogleApiClient mGoogleApiClient;
protected LocationRequest mLocationRequest;
protected Location mCurrentLocation;
public static final long UPDATE_INTERVAL_IN_MILLISECONDS = 30000L;
public static final long FASTEST_UPDATE_INTERVAL_IN_MILLISECONDS = 15000L;

public IBinder onBind(Intent arg0)
{

    Log.i(TAG, "ONBIND WAS RUN!!");

    return this.myBinder;
}

public class MyLocalBinder
        extends Binder
{
    public MyLocalBinder() {}

    MyLocationService getService()
    {
        return MyLocationService.this;
    }
}

protected void createLocationRequest()
{
    Log.i(TAG, "createLocationRequest() was run");
    this.mLocationRequest = new LocationRequest();

    this.mLocationRequest.setInterval(UPDATE_INTERVAL_IN_MILLISECONDS);

    this.mLocationRequest.setFastestInterval(FASTEST_UPDATE_INTERVAL_IN_MILLISECONDS);

    // TODO find out what this means
    this.mLocationRequest.setPriority(LocationRequest.PRIORITY_BALANCED_POWER_ACCURACY);
}
```

As you can see, I set the priority to BALANCED_POWER_ACCURACY and the update interval to 30 seconds.

So... everything seemed to be working fine, but it seems that in AT LEAST ONE case, where user is using an HTC one... when their phone is in sleep mode (I am assuming it is called sleep mode... what I mean is basically any time that the screen goes dark on its own), the updates from their phone go from a 30 second interval to a 5 MINUTE INTERVAL. (I can see this from the server side).

I am troubled by this apparent fact that the interval explicitly defined is arbitrarily (?) ignored.  I need to have a dependable interval in order for the server to determine whether someone is actively available or not.

I will do more testing of other phones, but in the meantime, does anyone have any experience with this -- Google play location services in a bound intentservice, using BALANCED POWER mode, and why the interval would be affected by the sleep(?) mode of the phone that the app is running on?  I thought that google play services used wakelocks automatically and so we weren't supposed to have to worry about that stuff.

Thanks for any help, I will update with any findings.

UPDATE: I have tested using a galaxy S4, and it also seems to ignore/alter my stated desired update interval only if unplugged, AND power button pressed to put to sleep.  In the case of this phone, it seems to average a 1.5 minute interval with a max of 5 minutes... that is until it comes back out of sleep mode and it's back to the 30 seconds (approx) that I set in code.

UPDATE 2: I tried using mLocationRequest.setMaxWaitTime(31000), but this did not seem to have any effect.

Comment: What is your service bound to? I don't think a [bound service](https://developer.android.com/guide/components/bound-services.html) means what you think it means.

Comment: its been working fine (except for the stated problem) for 7 months.  My understanding of bound services is as follows: https://developer.android.com/guide/components/bound-services.html

Comment: If nothing in your app is actually calling `bindService` with your Service, then that code does nothing at all. Of course, Google Play service's location doesn't require a bound service (it'll start your app and deliver results whether your service is alive or not, assuming you're using the `PendingIntent` version).

Comment: (NOTE: I'm quite sure that the question of whether I'm using the best possible implementations is irrelevant to the problem at hand.. I'm relatively new and wouldn't know the best possible way... but this way works so far) ... bindService is called from my MainActivity.   the toggle button in MainActivity starts/stops the location service.   [ continued ]

Comment: I chose an Intentservice because I wanted it to be on a seaparet thread... since it does work inside onLocationChanged().  As I understand, Intent services normally terminate themselves after their work is done, however I wanted to keep the service alive until it is toggled off, hence the use of bound service.  It is working just fine, the problem I am trying to address is with the update interval changing depending on the "mode" (plugged in or not, sleep mode or not) of the phone the app is running on.  Thanks for any help.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Per the [setInterval() documentation](https://developers.google.com/android/reference/com/google/android/gms/location/LocationRequest.html#setInterval(long)):

> This interval is inexact. You may not receive updates at all (if no location sources are available), or you may receive them slower than requested.

There is no guarantee that the `setInterval()` timing will be consistent with the interval you set. You can only assume that since you have not received any new location, the device has not changed position.

In any case, the timing of getting location requests does not depend on any state within your application (whether you are using a bound service or not) and is managed entirely by the Google Play services app.

Comment: I forgot that I read that once... I've just been getting such consistent location updates* (every 25-40 seconds when set to 30000ms) that I forgot it wasnt guaranteed.  * I can say for sure that regardless of device position, when using BALANCED_POWER mode, the interval ONLY (in my tests on 2 different devices) becomes inconsistent (seeminly random intervals up to 5 mins) when the device is in standby/sleep (whatever mode it is when you push the power button).

Comment: Would you be interested in a quick version of my app that demonstrates the issue?